# PHP & jQuery Report Builder

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-ui-draggable

I am looking to build an easy Report Tool for users on my site. They will be able to grab items like, (Get All Contacts that have notes), (Get All Contacts that have XXX items)

Features:
- Drag and Drop items on-to a page (jQuery UI)
---> Each item will have PHP code grabbing items from a database (Contacts/notes, etc)
- Print the report to either a PDF or direct to printer
- Save the report so they can come back to it and edit it with more drag and drop if needed.

I know this is quite complex, I have found this, and think it could be a start to 'saving' the reports that were made into a database.
http://daffl.github.com/jquery.dform/

Another potential example, would be Google Analytics Dashboards, they are extremely powerful. I don't need that complexity, but something simple like this.

Any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you managed to find something?

Comment: Not yet... I can 'build' forms, but not really a reporting

Comment: Did you manage to find something yet ?

Comment: No I haven't. I haven't really been searching for it any-longer. I think it would have to be very custom and setup with a form of API and flexible framework. Pull in all the json data, and take that jQuery-ui-builder and format something along those lines. Vague I know, but I haven't built anything yet either.